Nginx SSL configuration for Angular website not working - white screen
I'm trying to serve my Angular website over SSL with Nginx. The website works fine on port 80, but when I enable SSL on port 443, all I get is a white screen, and the website doesn’t lo
Here is my current setup:
user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    ### HTTP Server Block - Redirects all requests to HTTPS ###
    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  “DomainName“ www.“DomainName“.com;

        ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/“DomainName“/fullchain.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/“DomainName“/privkey.key;

        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;

        ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    }
}

Dockerfile
# Stage 1: Build the Angular app
FROM node:18-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build --prod

# Stage 2: Serve with Nginx
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY ssl/fullchain.crt /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainname.com/fullchain.crt
COPY ssl/privkey.key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainname.com/privkey.key
RUN chmod 700 /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainname.com/
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

COPY --from=build /app/dist/portfolio /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80

roblem Description:
The site works without issues over HTTP (port 80).
When I enable HTTPS (port 443), I only get a white
I have combined the HTTP and HTTPS configuration in one server block, as described here:
https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html
Does anyone have an idea of what might be causing this?
I’d appreciate any help!
